# Why cannot top level module be set to main in Hint

Tags: haskell, ghc, hint, ghc-api

Why cannot top level module be set to "Main" in Hint (Language.Haskell.Interpreter)?

Allow me to demonstrate:

```
module Main where

import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
import Control.Monad

main = do 
  res <- runInterpreter (test "test")
  case res of
       Left e -> putStrLn (show e)
       Right t -> putStrLn (show t) 
  return ()

test :: String -> Interpreter ()
test mname = 
  do
    loadModules [mname ++ ".hs"]
    setTopLevelModules ["Main"]
```

Will result in:

```
NotAllowed "These modules are not interpreted:\nMain\n"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hint/0.3.3.2/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v:setTopLevelModules) says, top level modules have to be interpreted, i.e. not compiled.

When loading a module, a compiled version will be used if it's available. The [GHCi manual](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/ghci-compiled.html) has more detailed information on this.

I'm guessing there's a `test.o` and `test.hi` in the same folder from an earlier build. I was able to reproduce the error with these files present. Deleting them solves the problem, as the module will then be interpreted.

You can also force a module to be loaded in interpreted mode by prefixing the module name with an asterisk, e.g. `loadModules ["*" ++ mname ++ ".hs"]`.

Comment: I can't really tell my users to delete their object files before running the code. Tricky...

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that it compiles the code OK, but then when it goes back to load the current interpreted modules, a problem occurs.

It loads `Main` with [findModule](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hint/0.2/doc/html/src/Language-Haskell-Interpreter-GHC.html), but, apparently, loads the wrong `Main`: It's loading the application `Main`, which indeed was not interpreted, sees that, and dies.

(Though I should add I haven't used Hint so I'm kind of guessing ;)