# How do I force interpretation in Hint

Tags: haskell, ghc, hint, ghc-api

How do I force interpretation mode in Hint (Language.Haskell.Interpreter)?

I have this code:

```
module Main where

import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
import Control.Monad

main = do 
  res <- runInterpreter (test "test")
  case res of
       Left e -> putStrLn (show e)
       Right t -> putStrLn (show t) 
  return ()

test :: String -> Interpreter ()
test mname = 
  do
    loadModules [mname ++ ".hs"]
    setTopLevelModules ["Main"]
```

Will result in (based on the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7134520/17500)):

```
NotAllowed "These modules are not interpreted:\nMain\n"
```

only if GHC finds test.o!

I've tried

```
unsafeSetGhcOption ("-fbyte-code")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`-fforce-recomp`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#recomp) option seems to force interpretation when used from GHCi/Hint.

```
unsafeSetGhcOption "-fforce-recomp"
```

Although I could not find any documentation to verify this, it seems reasonable that GHCi/Hint would reuse the recompilation checking from GHC.

---

**UPDATE**: Digging around a bit more I found [GHC ticket #2542](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2542), where it is stated that prefixing the module name with an asterisk will force interpretation in GHCi. 
This is also confirmed in [the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html).

```
:load *test.hs
```

This appears to carry over to Hint as well, so this also works:

```
loadModules ["*" ++ mname ++ ".hs"]
```